# Python regular expression slicing

Tags: python, html, regex

I am trying to get a web page using the following sample code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
print urlopen("http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php").read()
```

Now I can get the whole web page in a variable. I wanna get a part of the page containing something like this

```
<div class="methodsynopsis dc-description">
   <span class="type">string</span><span class="methodname"><b>gettext</b></span> ( <span class="methodparam"><span class="type">string</span> <tt class="parameter">$message</tt></span>
   )</div>
```

So that i can generate a file to implement in another application.
I wanna be able to extract the words "string", "gettext" and "$message".

Comment: Variations of this question have been asked many times on SO.  This is the definitive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using BeautifulSoup

- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Example code :

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldoc)
allSpans = soup.findAll('span', class="type")
for element in allSpans:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

When extracting information from HTML, it isn't recommended to just hack some regexes together. The *right* way to do it is to use a proper HTML parsing module. Python has several good modules for this purpose - in particular I recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Don't be put off by the name - it's a serious module used by a lot of people with great success. The [documentation page](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) has a lot of examples that should help you get started with your particular needs.